# Llamar a una ruta desde cualquier vista

Tags: laravel

Como puedo llamar a esta ruta desde cualquier vista. La idea es llamarla para hacer un foreach con los datos arrojados

```
Route::get('/', function (){
        $ultimosPresupuestoRecibidos = Presupuesto::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
        return $ultimosPresupuestoRecibidos;
    });
```

Comment: Cualquier vista de un mismo controller o desde distintos?

Comment: en principio me bastaria con un mismo controller, para entenderlo un poco más @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esa ruta que planeas recuperar en múltiples vistas lo que devuelve es el valor de una consulta, por tanto considero que lo pudieras plantear de esta forma:

- Declara una propiedad dentro de la clase de tu controlador (donde están todos los métodos que llaman a las vistas a donde planeas enviar esta data)
- Declara en un método constructor en la clase del controlador para la asignación de la consulta a la propiedad
- Posterior para acceder a esta propiedad que contiene la consulta y poder mandar el valor a todas tus vistas, puedes hacerlo por medio de la sintaxis de: **`$this->variable`**

Código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Presupuesto;

class TuController extends Controller
{
    public $consulta;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->consulta = Presupuesto::latest('id')->limit(5)->get();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view("tu-vista")->with(["consulta" => $this->consulta]);
    }

    public function otroMetodo()
    {
        return view("tu-otra-vista")->with(["consulta" => $this->consulta]);
    }
}
```

Incluso como estamos enviando la data a las vistas por medio de una estructura de array asociativo, si necesitas mandar mas información  entonces solo debería quedar de esta forma:

```
view("vista")->with([
                     "consulta" => $this->consulta,
                     "otra-consulta" => $otraconsulta
                   ]);
```

Considera que de está forma:

- Quitas de las rutas tu consulta
- Podrás obtener en todas las vistas que sirva tu controlador la data de la misma consulta sin tener que rescribirla
- Por cada ruta declarada que haga uso de este controlador y sus métodos entonces podrás enviar los datos de esta consulta, que entiendo sería el punto final que buscas

Comment: Una  pregunta @BetaM y no hay que hacer un `route` ?

Comment: No entiendo a ¿qué te refieres con `route`? @Miguel, ¿hablas de `Route::verbo`?

Comment: Para llamar al controlador, o ya directamente puedo hacer un foreach en la vista?

Comment: Moví simplemente la consulta que tenías en el archivo de Rutas al contexto del controlador, el llamado al controlador y a los métodos lo vas a tener que seguir haciendo igual, lo único que propongo es que la consulta se construye 1 vez y después la puedes mandar a cualquier vista en cada método del controlador donde la invoques

Comment: Pero en el route ya no tengo que hacer la consulta no? ya esta en el controlador pues se quedaria así? `Route::get('/', 'Home@index');`  jajjaja no lo creo :S

Comment: y la variable para hacer el foreach seria `$consulta`??

Comment: @Miguel lo que vas a seguir invocando en el archivo de rutas, según la url que determines en cada caso será **el controlador y al método deseado**, si la variable para iterar los datos en la vista será `$consulta` o de hecho la que tu le determines

Comment: Te explico, algo he hecho mal, hice tu primer paso, para no cambiar datos, luego en routes puse esto así `Route::get('/', 'Home@index');` y luego para el foreach tal que así `@foreach ($consulta as $presupuesto)` pero me dice que la variable $consulta no existe @BetaM

Comment: Y tu controlador es `Home` o `HomeController` ? por que todo parace indicar que lo escribiste mal

Comment: Es `Home` cree yo un controlador para hacer pruebas

Comment: ¿Y si la mandaste a la vista con la misma sintaxis de mi respuesta?, por que la misma esta basada en un ejemplo  (funcional) recién hecho

Comment: no lo se lo único que hice en mi controller la parte de `public function __construct()` por lo demas lo deje todo igual para probar primero y ya luego cambiaba los datos

Comment: Pues lo único que veo posible es que te hayas equivocado al escribir o copiar el ejemplo, de ahí en mas no logro identificar que tuvieras mal

Comment: Puede ser por la ruta del `GET` ya que tengo otra ruta que carga ahi? realmente tiene que cargar en `/admin`

Comment: Revisa si en el controlador, dentro del método que sirve cada una de las vistas donde deseas ver esta información si le estás mandando la variable como muestro en el código, pues si te dice que no existe es por que no la estás mandando a esa vista

Comment: Lo he probado en otra vista limpia, que solo carga los layouts y me sucede lo mismo solo me trae la información que tengo en el controlador en la parte de `@index` evidentemente tengo que tener algo mal, quizas esto esta construido con otra metodologia y no es compatible con lo que me comentas @BetaM

Comment: Ya no se me ocurre que mas podrías revisar, pues me dices que has seguido la propuesta, entonces en este punto entonces esperemos el aporte de alguien mas

Comment: Para nada @BetaM es fallo de mi estructuración no lo hice bien, tu respuesta es muy correcta! solo que ahora tengo que reconstruir unas cuantas cosas, gracias por tu ayuda!